# Returning user defined objects using dependency injection

Tags: c#, architecture, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm using Ninject for dependency injection and I've got it working nicely when passing fundamental types, but I'm unsure of the best way to structure the application once I begin passing custom object types.

Here's a simple example. I have 4 projects: Main, Project A, Project B and Interfaces. Main references ProjectA, ProjectB and Interfaces and both Project A and ProjectB refrence Interfaces.

In Interfaces I've defined an interface IClassA which has a single method which returns an int.

```
public interface IClassA
{
    int ReturnFundamental();
}
```

In ProjectA I have ClassA which implements IClassA.

```
public class ClassA : IClassA
{
    public int ReturnFundamental()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

ProjectB contains ClassB which accepts IClassA as constructor based dependancy injection. It also provides a method that allows me to call the method defined in IClassA and implemented in ClassA.

```
public class ClassB
{
    private readonly IClassA classA;
    public ClassB(IClassA classA)
    {
        this.classA = classA;
    }
    public void GetObject()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(classA.ReturnFundamental());
    }
}
```

The Main project sets up Ninject, binds IClassA to ClassA, instantiates an instance of ClassB and calls a method on ClassB.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Bind<IClassA>().To<ClassA>();
    var classB = kernel.Get<ClassB>();
    classB.GetObject();
    Console.Read();
}
```

This all works great, ClassB can call a method in ClassA and is returned the value. However if I don't want to return a fundamental type, but instead want to return a custom object I've defined, what's the nicest way of doing that?

If I'm not mistaken then IClassA, ClassA and ClassB would all need a reference to this object, and defining it in the same project as ClassA or ClassB causes the coupling that dependency injection was used to avoid.

So the only solution I can think of is to either:

1. Declare all the objects in the Interfaces project
2. Create another project to put all the objects that are used to pass data between interfaces.
3. Create a new project containing all the objects required for a single interaction between classes, where every interaction has it's own project it references containing all the objects it requires.

The problem I see with the first option is that it would not be clear what objects are used by what classes and I fear the Interfaces project would become too large, containing too much information in a single location.

The second option shares the same issue as the first in that it would not be clear what objects are used by what classes but at least it separates the interfaces from the objects only used to pass data. It would however add a lot more references between projects as (assuming every interfaces passes at least one object) every interface and every class either implementing that interface or using that interface would need a reference to the new project.

The third option at least makes it clear which class interactions require which objects as they're all grouped together, however it would result in a lot of projects being created.

I imagine there's a nice solution to this, as it must be a very common problem, but I'm not sure of the best implementation on a large project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to create an interface project.
What one normally does is declare implementation (-details) as internal and interfaces as public. For example.

```
public class PersonInfo
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string Surname { get; set; }
    Address Address { get; set; }
}

public interface IPersonSearchService
{
    IEnumerable<PersonInfo> Search(string keyword);
}

internal class PersonSearchService : IPersonSearchService
{
    ....
}
```

now you add a NinjectModule:

```
public class PersonSearchServiceModule : NinjectModule 
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        this.Bind<IPersonSearchService>().To<PersonSearchService>();
    }
}
```

and in the Composition Root (Application Project, Main Project,.. whatchamacallit) you load the module, either explicitly by `kernel.Load<PersonSearchServiceModule>()` or all `Module` of one (or multiple) assembly by the `kernel.Load(IEnumerable<Assembly>)` overload.

Using [Feature-Namespaces](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2012/01/25/3077/) is a good idea, too.

Comment: But then every project that has to call this interface must reference the whole project, including the class itself. Doesn't this defeat the point of DI for de-coupling? In case it's relevant, my idea for separating the interfaces into their own project was taken from [this microsoft tutorial](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/mtaulty/Prism--Silverlight-Part-2-Dependency-Injection-with-Unity).

Comment: What point exactly is defeated by doing this? ;-) Sure i agree it's not *exactly* the same as putting the interfaces in a separate projects and *sometimes* it may be necessary or sensible to do so, but in the vast majority of cases it's not. An example where it's useful to have the interface in a separate project is when you define an interface of an extension point whose *implementation* is unknown to the application and can be added later (--> plugin!).